# Is there a maximum number of public functions in a contract?

Tags: solidity, ganache

I have two contracts A and B, both deploy and work correctly in ganache (they both use less than 6M gas). Now I want to create a third contract C that inherit both A and B.

```
contract C is A, B {
}
```

This contract C fails to deploy with out of gas exception. But gas should not be an issue because ganache is configured with a block gas limit of 4 billion.

After trial and error commenting out my code, I found it fails with a public function in contract B. After reordering functions I found it doesn't matter which function in particular, it will fail if there are more than N public functions in contract B.

**Update:** Trying the deploy the same contracts in a geth private testnet causes the error "oversized data". So I think is not the number of public functions but the resulting contract is too big.

Comment: So i take it your tried changing the last `public` function to `internal` or `external` ?

Comment: Yes, changing function to internal or private will make it work. I didn't try external.

Comment: what is the exact error you are seeing, any chance its 'Stack too deep'?

Comment: @Legman As mentioned in the question the error out of gas when deploying the resulting contract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is exactly one place in geth code where "oversized data" is thrown. It's in `func (pool *TxPool) validateTx(tx *types.Transaction, local bool) error`.

> Heuristic limit, reject transactions over 32KB to prevent DOS attacks

Moreover, there is also a limit for bytecode size of a smart contract. It's 24576 bytes (see `protocol_params.go`).

`maxCodeSize` can be set in genesis.json. 32KB for TX size limit is a hard-coded constant in the code.

Comment: I think you are right, it is not about public functions, it is just happen that public function generate more code and that little extra pushes the code beyond the accepted size.

Comment: how to set maxCodeSize? is it under the config?

Comment: It‘s a constant in the code.