# How big could a contract be?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, gas

I am trying to figure out how big could a contract be? Is it possible to have 10k functions? One million? More?

Is there any restriction on the function's body size?

Does a bigger contract need more gas to be deployed?

Is a bigger contract slower than a smaller one?

Comment: You can distribute your code over several of contracts. You do not need to deploy the code in a single transaction.

Comment: Now there is the Diamond Standard that solves the max size issue: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/2535

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solidity contracts are compiled to EVM bytecode. Contract bytecode costs 200 gas per byte of bytecode, and since block gas limit is 8 million right now, you could *theoretically* get a ~40,000 (a little less since there's extra for deployment/tx data) byte contract deployed. It's unlikely that you'd be able to create a contract this size though since blocks don't usually have that much extra space already. Regarding execution speed, this is totally dependent on your implementation.

Edit: As pointed out by @Ismael, there's actually a 32kb limit per transaction as explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46541/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-public-functions-in-a-contract/46612#46612). That page also says there's also a 24576 byte limit for contract size, so I stand corrected! The EIP for the contract byte limit can be found [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md).

Edit2: If you're looking for a formal explanation for the contract size limit, check out definition 97 of the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

[image: Yellow Paper Definition 97]

That is, the output size of the final body code must not be bigger than 24576 bytes.

Comment: Also you have hard limit of 32kb per transaction https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/46612/.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the contract size limitation by using the Transparent Contract Standard: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1538