# Is there a limit on how many events a contract can emit and how many mappings it can have?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, storage, factory

I read somewhere that there is a limit on the amount of data that can be stored in a contract. And so there is a limit on how big arrays can be.

Now I am wondering is there a limit on how many mappings a contract can have? And is there a limit on how many events a contract can emit?

I am asking this to understand how a factory contract would store pointers if it had many child contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (theoretical) total storage for a contract is 2^256 * 32 bytes regardless of how you store it. That number is huge, you'll run into issues long before filling that storage.

I don't think there's a max number of Events that you can emit. However you'll probably limited by gas cost and block gas limit.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am wondering is there a limit on how many mappings a contract can have? And is there a limit on how many events a contract can emit?

The practical limit for this is the transaction cost. You can in theory pump data to Ethereum blockchain at the rate of around few megabyte a minute, but you would pay billions of dollars per month for the transaction cost.

> I am asking this to understand how a factory contract would store pointers if it had many child contracts.

Someone pays the transaction cost and the storage of a pointer is roughly the cost of executing `SSTORE` EVM instructions.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am wondering is there a limit on how many mappings a contract can have?

If you mean variables of type `mapping`, and not entries in a particular mapping, then you'll eventually be limited by the maximum contract (code) size, [which is 24kB](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47539/how-big-could-a-contract-be). (Though I think if you had *that* many mappings then you'd need to reconsider your contract design... )